# How to create a delegatable implicit account via command line? I want to delegate to a baker from a TZ1 address

Tags: delegating, account, ubuntu, delegation

Is this possible?  If so, what is the command?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try it but the "normal" way doesn't work?

```
./tezos-client set delegate for "my_implicit" to "delegate"
```

[image: Source: https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html?highlight=set%20delegate]

Source: https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html?highlight=set%20delegate

Since Babylon, there is no need to "flag" an implicit account as "delegatable"

"In protocol 005, tz accounts which are not registered as delegate can be delegated towards a tz account registered as delegate"

Source: https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/005_babylon.html#make-implicit-accounts-delegatable

Just the other way around is still needed.

Comment: How do you create the account though? Also, when I use that command I get an error